# Product of compact hereditarily Lindelöf spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be two Hausdorff,  compact hereditarily Lindelöf spaces. Then with product topology, is $X\times Y$ hereditarily Lindelöf?

We know that the product of two Lindelöf spaces may not be Lindelöf. But the product of a Lindelöf space with a compact space is Lindelöf. Therefore, I am wondering the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [split interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) is compact and hereditarily Lindelöf. The product of two split intervals is not hereditarily Lindelöf, because it contains the Sorgenfrey plane as a subspace.